# Intel iMac Ubuntu Installation Troubleshooting

Tags: 12.04, boot, virtualbox, mac, dvd

I'm having terrible luck trying to install any flavor of Ubuntu on my 2006 5,1 Intel Core 2 Duo iMac. I've downloaded the 32-bit and 64-bit current and past version, as well as tried torrent installations. The .iso files install perfectly in VirtualBox, as well as an old HP Pavilion laptop. When I burn the .iso to DVD, the file structure appears, REFit and REFind detect a generic Linux DVD, as well as a "Windows" DVD.

But here's the trouble:

The installation process never begins, always ending with a black screen and the message "No operating system found." The DVD is not booted when depressing the "C".

I'm wondering if there is a problem with the external LG M-DISC Super Multi USB DVD drive I'm using on the iMac. Months ago, I was able to install Lubuntu on the iMac using an LG slimline USB DVD drive. I replaced the slimline because it would not recognize OS X 10.6 or 10.7.

Because the installer boots on the Windows machine as well as the virtual box, but not the iMac's external DVD drive, is there a problem with Linux discs booting on this particular LG drive?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat. You need to do a few things:

It helps to use the mac modifications from this site:
https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/

Once you boot from the DVD, push F6 and select "no acpi". That helped for me.